# What is the maximum number of players in basketball?

Tags: rules, basketball

One of the questions during my competitive exam was:

> According to the fundamental rules of basketball, at any time, a maximum of (i).... players from both teams, and a maximum of (ii)... players from each team, are required to be present on the court.

The options were:

> 1. 12, 5
> 2. 12, 6
> 3. 10, 5
> 4. 14, 6

I answered number 3. However, today the official answers were by the organisation, and according to them no. 1 is right answer. Who is correct?

---

Here's the original question; the correct answer is marked in green:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As written, (3) is the right answer as 5 players from each team are on the court at any one time. Quoting [Article 4.2.2 of the FIBA rules](http://www.fiba.basketball/OBR2017/Final.pdf):

> During playing time 5 players from each team shall be on the playing court

This obviously means that there are 10 players when you count both teams. However, making half a question "can you add five and five?" seems an obvious error, so I suspect they meant to ask something else. It is possibly worth noting that the limit of players (on and off the court) for one team is 12; quoting Article 4.2.1:

> Each team shall consist of: No more than 12 team members entitled to play

*Maybe* this is what the question was meant to ask.